# Elastic Search Aggregation and Details

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to get the teachers name too in this query..
From this I am able to get loop the teachers and get the number of classes she is working for and also the amount of money she gets for each year.
But I can't get full details in this query. I want to display teachers name too.

here is my current query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "teacher": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "teacher_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "academic_year": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "acc_year",
            "interval": "year"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "income": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "teacher_hourly_fee"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: How does your mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward approach may be to combine teacher ID and name as a generated term using a script:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "teacher" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : "_source.teacher_id + '-' + _source.teacher_name",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adjust script particulars per your actual schema.